Labeled[..,..,Above] giving MapThread::mptd errors
As far as I see there is no single thing on the internet with errorcode MapThread::mptd being associated with the Labeled function and I can't find the inside details of this function to verify the cause of this problem so I feel compelled to ask for your help.
My code:
data={{"I [uA]", "V1(X) [V]", "V2(Y)  [V]"}, {28.282`, 0, 0}, {"", 0.07`, 
  0.02`}, {"", 0.12`, 0.04`}, {"", 0.18`, 0.066`}, {"", 0.25`, 
  0.081`}, {"", 1, 0.082`}, {13.247`, 1, 0.037`}, {"", 0.2`, 
  0.036`}, {"", 0.13`, 0.027`}, {"", 0.09`, 0.016`}, {"", 0.06`, 
  0.011`}, {"", 0.02`, 0}, {43.353`, 0, 0}, {"", 0.06`, 0.025`}, {"", 
  0.1`, 0.045`}, {"", 0.16`, 0.075`}, {"", 0.22`, 0.105`}, {"", 0.32`,
   0.127`}, {"", 1, 0.128`}, {58.43`, 1, 0.178`}, {"", 0.4`, 
  0.177`}, {"", 0.28`, 0.147`}, {"", 0.2`, 0.112`}, {"", 0.16`, 
  0.086`}, {"", 0.07`, 0.033`}, {"", 0, 0}, {73.608`, 0, 0}, {"", 
  0.07`, 0.042`}, {"", 0.14`, 0.081`}, {"", 0.22`, 0.133`}, {"", 
  0.31`, 0.183`}, {"", 0.44`, 0.225`}, {"", 1, 0.226`}, {88.591`, 1, 
  0.275`}, {"", 0.5`, 0.274`}, {"", 0.43`, 0.26`}, {"", 0.3`, 
  0.195`}, {"", 0.23`, 0.151`}, {"", 0.13`, 0.086`}, {"", 0.04`, 
  0.027`}, {"", 0, 0}};
pdata[n_] := 
  Module[{m = {6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8}}, f[x_] := 1 + Accumulate[m][[x]]; 
   g[x_] := f[x] - m[[x]] + 1; data[[g[n] ;; f[n]]]];
ListPlot[
 Table[Labeled[pdata[7 - i][[All, 2 ;; 3]], 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(B\)]\)=" <> 
    ToString[pdata[7 - i][[1, 1]]] <> " \[Mu]A", Above], {i, 6}], 
 PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 1]

Gives

and the plot

I based my code on https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/visualization--labels-scales-exclusions/new-labeling-system.html.en?footer=lang

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! I can confirm this happening in version 13.3, but it seems to be fixed in version 14.1 (or before).

Mine is 14.0.0, I might try getting newer version, but will still appreciate if someone comes up with explaination and/or solution within this one

This seems to be a bug, that I can't reproduce in 14.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit). Please spend some time improving your question, as it's currently at risk of being closed. Explain that you need a workaround the bug for a specific version.
